# Indexing field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In Solr schema we are defining the index for the field to be true/false which is being helpful in search query.

e.g. :

```
<field name="features" type="text" **indexed="true"** stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

How to achieve the same functionality in ElasticSearch. I know there is a mapping called "_index" but not sure about the functionality of it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

When you define a mappping you can use the "index" attribute but it is not a boolean. It can hold one of three values. As stated in elastic docs:

> The index attribute controls how the string will be indexed. It can contain one of three values: 
>   ***analyzed***
>   : First analyze the string and then index it. In other words, index this field as full text.
>   ***not_analyzed***
>   : Index this field, so it is searchable, but index the value exactly as specified. Do not analyze it.
>   ***no***
>   : Don’t index this field at all. This field will not be searchable.
>   The default value of index for a string field is analyzed. If we want to map the field as an exact value, we need to set it to not_analyzed:

The usage is:

```
"field_name": {
    "type":     "string",
    "index":    "not_analyzed"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. So you mean there are three value for the attribute "_index" as below. 1). analyzed - This will do partial match for the field and field will be searchable in search query. 2). not_analyzed - This will do the exact match for the field value and field will be searchable in search query. 3).no - This field will not be searchable in search query.